# detect string case and apply to another one

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

**How can I detect the case (lowercase, UPPERCASE, CamelCase [, maybe WhATevERcAse]) of a string to apply to another one?**

I would like to do it as a oneline with sed or whatever.

This is used for a spell checker which proposes corrections.

Let's say I get something like string_to_fix:correction:

- `BEHAVIOUR:behavior` => get `BEHAVIOUR:BEHAVIOR`
- `Behaviour:behavior` => get `Behaviour:Behavior`
- `behaviour:behavior` => remains `behaviour:behavior`

Extra case to be handled:

- `MySpecalCase:myspecialcase` => `MySpecalCase:MySpecialCase` (so character would be the point of reference and not the position in the word)

Comment: wrt your `WhATevERcAse` requirement: Would the right side of `BehAvioUr:behavior` become `BehAvior` or `BehAvioR` or something else? Include those cases in your example if you want them handled. Also explain what the rule is for converting characters - relative position in the string or value of the character or something else? Can you have quite different strings like `TheRe:their`? If so include that in your sample too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/([A-Z]+):(.*)/\1:\U\2/;s/([A-Z][a-z]+):([a-z])/\1:\U\2\L/' file
```

**Explanations:**

- `s/([A-Z]+):(.*)/\1:\U\2/`: search for uppercase letters up to `:` and using backreference and uppercase modifier `\U`, change letters after `:` to uppercase
- `s/([A-Z][a-z]+):([a-z])/\1:\U\2\L/` : search for words starting with uppercase letter and if found, replace first letter after `:` to uppercase

Answer (score 4):

With awk you can use the posix character classes to detect case:

```
$ cat case.awk
/^[[:lower:]]+$/ { print "lower"; next }
/^[[:upper:]]+$/ { print "upper"; next }
/^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+$/ { print "capitalized"; next }
/^[[:alpha:]]+$/ { print "mixed case"; next }
{ print "non alphabetic" }

Jims-MacBook-Air so $ echo chihuahua | awk -f case.awk
lower

Jims-MacBook-Air so $ echo WOLFHOUND | awk -f case.awk
upper

Jims-MacBook-Air so $ echo London | awk -f case.awk
capitalized

Jims-MacBook-Air so $ echo LaTeX | awk -f case.awk
mixed case

Jims-MacBook-Air so $ echo "Jaws 2" | awk -f case.awk
non alphabetic
```

Here's an example taking two strings and applying the case of the first to the second:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS = ":" }
$1 ~ /^[[:lower:]]+$/ { print $1, tolower($2); next }
$1 ~ /^[[:upper:]]+$/ { print $1, toupper($2); next }
$1 ~ /^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+$/ { print $1, toupper(substr($2,1,1)) tolower(substr($2,2)); next }
$1 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/ { print $1, $2; next }
{ print $1, $2 }

$ echo BEHAVIOUR:behavior | awk -f case.awk
BEHAVIOUR:BEHAVIOR

$ echo Behaviour:behavior | awk -f case.awk
Behaviour:Behavior

$ echo behaviour:behavior | awk -f case.awk
behaviour:behavior
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can do the same with sed, but that doesn't tell me how to apply it to the new string.

Comment: thanks a lot, that works. I prefer the sed oneliner as it is more synthetic, although maybe less readable.

Comment: The accepted sed solution is also non-portable and, maybe more importantly, doesn't do what you asked for with `WhATevERcAse`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F ':' '
   {
   # read Pattern to reproduce
   Pat = $1
   printf("%s:", Pat)

   # generic
   if ( $1 ~ /^[:upper:]*$/) { print toupper( $2); next}
   if ( $1 ~ /^[:lower:]*$/) { print tolower( $2); next}

   # Specific 
   gsub( /[^[:upper:][:lower:]]/, "~:", Pat)
   gsub( /[[:upper:]]/, "U:", Pat)
   gsub( /[[:lower:]]/, "l:", Pat)

   LengPat = split( Pat, aDir, /:/)

   # print with the correponsing pattern
   LenSec = length( $2)

   for( i = 1; i <= LenSec; i++ ) {
      ThisChar = substr( $2, i, 1)

      Dir = aDir[ (( i - 1) % LengPat + 1)] 
      if ( Dir == "U" ) printf( "%s", toupper( ThisChar))
       else if ( Dir == "l" ) printf( "%s", tolower( ThisChar))
        else printf( "%s", ThisChar)
      }
    printf( "\n")
    }' YourFile
```

- take all case (and taking same concept as @Jas for quick upper or lower pattern)
- works for this strucure only (spearator by `:`)
- second part (text) could be longer than part1, pattern is used cyclingly

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^([^:]*):\1$/Is//\1:\1/' file
```

This uses the `I` flag to do a caseless match and then replaces both instances of the match with the first.